# Kill all background jobs

Tags: bash

Is there a more compact form of killing background jobs than:

```
for i in {1..5}; do kill %$i; done
```

Also, {1..5} obviously has a hard-coded magic number in it, how can I make it "N" with N being the right number, without doing a:

```
$(jobs | wc -l)
```

I actually use \j in PS1 to get the # of managed jobs, is this equivalent?

Comment: `kill $(jobs -p)` seems easier.

Comment: I would prefer to kill jobs individually, if possible. (I might have misunderstood your comment, though)

Comment: `for pid in $(jobs -p); do kill $pid; done`?

Comment: @jw013 It's not only easier, it's actually correct (please post it as an answer), unlike a solution based on counting the lines of the output of `jobs` which only works if the jobs happen to be numbered consecutively. Oh, and “kill jobs individually” is meaningless: passing multiple PIDs to the `kill` command does exactly the same thing as passing them separately.

Comment: I was entering the command incorrectly, kill $(jobs -p) words and looks very correct to me too. Ready to accept.

Comment: Incidentally, if you want to kill a fixed range of job ids, you can do e.g. `kill %{1..5}`.

Answer (score 183, accepted):

To just `kill` all background jobs managed by `bash`, do

```
kill $(jobs -p)
```

Note that since both `jobs` and `kill` are built into `bash`, you shouldn't run into any errors of the *Argument list too long* type.

Comment: Also for posterity, what bahamat thinks is the way to do it in `zsh` disqualifies them as any authority on the topic.

Comment: I feel like I should know this, but how does the '$' work here?

Comment: @fersarr [Here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/147420/9537) you go

Comment: @bahamat That doesn't actually work since the PID may be in field 2 or 3 depending on whether the job is one of %+ or %- or not. What works is `kill %${(k)^jobdirs}`, which is indeed longer; if you need to list the PIDs then you can use the even longer `${${jobstates#*:*:}%%=*}`.

Comment: On CentOS, my prompt is waiting for more input `>`

Comment: From @jw013's link: `It's very similar to the backticks \`\`.
It's called command substitution (posix specification) and it invokes a subshell.`, and `Unlike the backticks, the $(...) form can be nested.`

Comment: This answer is incorrect. This will not kill all the processes from the background jobs, but only the process group leaders. Try with `sleep 3333 | sleep 3333 &`; after `kill $(jobs -p)`, `jobs` will still show the background job as running -- only one of the 2 `sleep` processes will be killed.

Answer (score 26):

Use `xargs` instead of the `$(jobs -p)` subcommand, because if `jobs -p` is empty then the kill command will fail.

```
jobs -p | xargs kill
```

Comment: This has the same exact effect though , it prints the help and exits with code 123

Comment: The the command works fine on OSX but doesn't work on Debian

Comment: This works great on CentOS 6

Comment: `jobs -p | xargs -rn10 kill` will do better better if `jobs -p` does not return any PIDs. Note that `-r` option is GNU extension.

Comment: As mentioned above,  the `-r` is the short format for the `--no-run-if-empty` GNU extension to `xargs` which instructs it to *not* run the command if stdin has no data.

Answer (score 14):

I guess depending on what output `jobs -p` gives, the solution could be slightly different. In my case

```bsh
$ jobs -p
[1]  - 96029 running    some job
[2]  + 96111 running    some other job
```

Therefore, doing the following is no good.

```bsh
$ jobs -p | xargs kill
kill: illegal process id: [1]
```

On the other hand, running `kill $(jobs -p)` does work but entails a lot of error messages, since the non-PID strings get passed to `kill` as well.

Therefore, my solution is to `grep` the PID first and then use `xargs`, as follows:

```bsh
$ jobs -p | grep -o -E '\s\d+\s' | xargs kill
```

Comment: What shell are you using?  What does `echo $0` show?  What does `help jobs` show?  The output illustrated is [not POSIX-compliant](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/jobs.html); *any* implementation of `jobs` should have a `-p` option with the intended behavior.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I am using zsh, and that is the reason for the strange output. I switched to bash and `jobs -p` did only output PID. I've just learned that zsh is not completely POSIX-compliant.

Answer (score 7):

@pizdelect point is what brought me here.  Jobs spawned using pipes have multiple pids.  `jobs -p` is only going to provide the first.

```
for j in $(jobs | awk '{gsub("[^0-9]","",$1);printf "%%%s\n", $1}');do kill $j;done
```

If you want to get them all, you have to use the job ID.

Comment: Finally, this works and sends kill signal to all background process groups, sending it to all background processes. Parsing `jobs` output to find out jobs numbers, then passing job numbers to `kill` for _jobspec_ is the way to go. Can be shortened a bit to `for j in $(jobs | awk '{gsub("[^0-9]","",$1);print $1}'); do kill %$j; done`. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer to check if there's any jobs that exist before killing them - this way the script won't fail if there's nothing running.

It's also shorter to type. Throw this in your `.bash_profile`:

```
function killjobs () {
    JOBS="$(jobs -p)";
    if [ -n "${JOBS}" ]; then;
        kill -KILL ${JOBS};
    fi
}
```

Then run:

```
killjobs
```

To kill any jobs running.

Comment: Why do you use the KILL signal? If you use Bash, you could use `-r` with `jobs` to list only running jobs.

Comment: Because the question asker said to 'kill all background jobs' not 'terminate all background jobs'. I appreciate that it's possible they may have not been speaking exactly though, especially as they send a TERM in their example.

Comment: You should use KILL signal usually only, if nothing else works, because the processes can not do any cleanup tasks with the signal.

Comment: @jarno Yes, I understand. The question is does the question asker?

Comment: It is still possible that some of the processes are terminated when running the function before calling kill.

Answer (score 3):

In `bash` and `zsh` I would use something like this (after considering the comment from [pizdelect](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/313992/pizdelect) about the process group):

```
jobs -p | extract_pids | xargs --no-run-if-empty kill -TERM -- || true
```

where

```
extract_pids() {
    awk '{
        if (NF == 1) { print -$1 }
        else if (NF > 1) {
            if ($2 == "+" || $2 == "-") { print -$3 }
            else { print -$2 }
        }
    }'
}
```

As far as I tested `jobs -p` returns the `PID`s in `bash`, f.i.:

```
$ jobs -p
41659
```

but can have these formats in `zsh`, f.i.:

```
$ jobs -p
[1]    206 running    sleep 10
[2]  - 208 running    sleep 10
[3]  + 210 running    sleep 10
```

`extract_pids` tries to handle these (4) cases.

**Note**: checking the processes with `jobs -p` can return `PID`s, which are already gone at the time `xargs kill` is invoked, so we ignore errors with a trailing `|| true`.

Comment: That will only kill the job (process group) leaders, not the background *jobs*. Try with `sleep 3333 | sleep 3333 &`  -- only one of the sleep processes will be killed and `jobs` will still show the background job as running. You should negate the pids if you want to kill entire jobs, not just job leaders. Yes this is a problem with the other answers, too.

Answer (score 2):

I have several backgrounded compound commands I want to terminate gracefully, by sending SIGINT to each process, on macOS. None of the other solutions worked properly for that, so I came up with this:

```
jobs -p | xargs -n1 pkill -SIGINT -g
```

`jobs -p` lists background processes started by the current shell.

`xargs -n1` executes pkill once for each job.

`pkill -SIGINT -g` sends SIGINT (same as ctrl+c) to all processes in the process group.

Answer (score 2):

[The accepted answer by @jw013](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/43709/9597) works in most situations, except when a job has background jobs since only the group leader is killed. (@pizdelect identified this limitation in [this comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43527/kill-all-background-jobs#comment1098617_43709).)

@pizdelect also pointed out that `kill` accepts negative PID values to choose the whole process group in [this comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43527/kill-all-background-jobs#comment1098606_589500).

Furthermore, one might not want to `kill` `Stopped` jobs, hence `jobs -r` might be useful.

Combining all these elements, here's a solution that kills all running jobs, including background jobs:

`for i in $(jobs -rp); do kill -- "-$i"; done`

Here's a solution that kills all jobs, including background jobs:

`for i in $(jobs -p); do kill -- "-$i"; done`

Answer (score 1):

Processes can ignore some signals. However, `SIGKILL` can not be ignored nor caught to do cleanups. To ensure all background jobs managed by `bash` are killed, try,

```
kill -9 $(jobs -p)
```

Comment: Many answers have already discussed `jobs -p` and specifically `$(jobs -p)`, and a couple have mentioned the KILL signal, so you aren’t adding anything new.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like `jobs -p | xargs kill` does the job, however it produces some unwanted output piped to kill. Here I am grouping output of `jobs -p` by having/not having + or - character

```
function killjobs() {
    JOBS=$(jobs -p)
    echo $JOBS | grep -v "+\|-"| awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9
    echo $JOBS | grep "+\|-"| awk '{print $3}' | xargs kill -9
}
```

And later you can just call `killjobs`

Comment: Which shell do you run so that you get those +/- in `$(jobs -p)`?

Comment: zsh is a very common shell that has a non-POSIX-compliant `jobs` output, which does include plus and minus.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said already, <strike>`jobs -p | xargs kill`</strike> or <strike>`kill $(jobs -p)`</strike> is wrong as:

- `jobs -p` prints the process *group* ids, with extra information with `zsh`
- `kill number` kills the process with number as id, not process group. There's not even a guarantee that the process group ids returned by `jobs -p` will have a corresponding running process by the same number. And even if there is, kill will not kill the other processes in the job / process-group
- if there's no job in the job table, `kill` will be run without arguments causing an error.

Here you want to run either `kill -- -<pgid>` or `kill %<jobnumber>` for all the jobs.

With `bash` or other shells that only print the pgid upon `jobs -p`, you can do:

```
jobs -p | sed 's/^/-/' | xargs -r kill --
```

(`-r` being a GNU extension)

Note that it doesn't work in `dash` where `jobs` running in a subshell (because as part of a pipeline) only lists the jobs of that subshell. There, you could instead redirect the output of `jobs -p` to a temporary file and then run `sed|xargs` on it, but anyway `dash` is not really intended to be run interactively.

With `zsh`:

```
() { (($#)) && kill %${^@}; } ${(k)jobstates}
```

Where we pass the list of job numbers (the `k`eys of the `$jobstates` special associative array) to an anonymous function that runs kill with `%` prepended to the job number if its number of arguments is non-zero.

Answer (score 0):

Do the same, faster:

```
jobs -p | xargs -P100 kill
```

Runs 100 simultaneous kill threads

Answer (score 0):

```bash
kill_all_jobs () {
local jobs=$(jobs -r | sed -En 's/^\[([0-9]+)\].*$/%\1/p')
[ -n "$jobs" ] && kill $jobs
return 0
}
```

- `jobs` will also list jobs that have finished since the last time jobs were checked,¹ `-r` will exclude them.²
- The [`sed`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/) script will do the following:

  - Match each line against the regular expression using the “extended” syntax (`-E`) `^\[([0-9]+)\].*$` (`[digits]anything`),
  - if it does not match, print nothing (`-n`),³
  - if it does, replace (`s/`) the match (which will be the entire line because of `^…$`) with `%\1` (`%digits`) and *do* print the resulting line (`/p`). (Bash’s builtin `kill` will recognize `%jobnumber` as referring to that job.)
- We only run `kill` if `$jobs` is not empty, because running `kill` with no arguments would be an error. (Note that we cannot use `xargs -r kill` here because `xargs` can only invoke `/usr/bin/kill`, not Bash’s builtin `kill`, and the former does not know about the shell’s jobs.)
- The `return 0` prevents the function from returning 1 if there were no jobs, which would usually cause the shell to exit in `set -e` mode.

¹ Note that “checking jobs” does not necessarily mean “invoking `jobs`”: Apparently, an interactive shell will usually do so before each “primary prompt” (prompt for the next command), as casually mentioned by the documentation for Bash’s `set -b`. (I couldn’t find another mention of this in `man bash`…) To verify this, run `sleep 1 &` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> again after at least one second: `[1]+  Done    sleep 1` appears before the prompt. And to verify that this line is indeed included in the output of `jobs` without `-r`, compare the results of `output=$(jobs)`<kbd>Enter</kbd>`echo "$output"` and `output=$(jobs -r)`<kbd>Enter</kbd>`echo "$output"` (each at least one second after `sleep 1 &`). (Mysteriously, the line will appear both before the next prompt and in the variable with `output=$(jobs)`, but only in the file with `jobs > somefile`.)
² It will also exclude jobs paused with `SIGSTOP`, but I haven’t found a way to list them without including finished jobs, and [sending those jobs any signal other than `SIGKILL` or `SIGCONT` won’t do anything in the short-term, anyway](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/298644). …Nope, using Bash’s builtin `kill` in conjunction with `%jobnumber` seems special in this regard: It can terminate a paused `sleep inf &` even with `SIGTERM`. Maybe it also sends `SIGCONT` to a paused job? I couldn’t find this documented anywhere…
³ Every non-empty line printed by `jobs` should match this pattern [as per POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/jobs.html), but just in case…