# What is $() in a command?

Tags: bash, shell, command

What is `$()` in Linux Shell Commands?

For example:

```
chmod 777 $(pwd)
```

Comment: Note that there's no such thing as _the line shell command_. There are a number of shell applications available for Linux.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It's very similar to the backticks ``.

It's called [command substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html) ([posix specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_03)) and it invokes a subshell. The command in the braces of `$()` or between the backticks (`` `…` ``) is executed in a subshell and the output is then placed in the original command.

Unlike backticks, the `$(...)` form can be nested. So you can use command substitution inside another substitution.

There are also differences in escaping characters within the substitution. I prefer the `$(...)` form.

Comment: backticks can be nested as well. Note that trailing newline characters are removed from the output of the command.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas how can backticks be nested? You mean by ecxessive escaping?

Comment: Yes: like with `echo \`echo \\`echo foo\\`\` bar`

Comment: Any official reference saying that backticks are deprecated?

Comment: Found this answer: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126927/have-backticks-i-e-cmd-in-sh-shells-been-deprecated seems they are not deprecated. Changed my answer, thanks

Comment: Backticks can be nested as long as you don't care about portability (different shells have different quoting rules). Or about your sanity.

Comment: @Gilles, would you care to expand on that? Maybe in a Q/A. Which shell(s) don't support the Bourne or POSIX syntax? Or are you referring to the double-quotes that need escaped as well in Bourne/Korn where some others can live without?

Comment: @Gilles, OK replying to myself, `yash` does have trouble with the Bourne/Korn syntax it would seem. And POSIX leaves the behaviour mostly _unspecified_ when nesting with quotes.

Answer (score 5):

In POSIX or POSIX-like shells (`ksh`, `bash`, `ash`, `zsh`, `yash`...), it is like ``` `` ```: the command inside `$()` is executed and replaced by its standard output. Word-splitting and filename generation are done unless `$()` is inside double-quotes. Thus

```
chmod 777 $(pwd)
```

should be replaced with:

```
chmod 777 "$(pwd)"
```

to avoid word-splitting and filename generation on the current working directory path.

Or even better (except under some shells, like zsh, in case the directory has been renamed):

```
chmod 777 "$PWD"
```

Since `$PWD` is a special variable that holds the path to the current working directory in POSIX shells.

Or even better:

```
chmod 777 .
```

Since the `.` entry in the current directory is a hard link to that directory itself.

Answer (score 3):

This `$()` is used for executing a command mostly inside some other command.

```
chmod 777 $(pwd)
```

`pwd` command gives the current working directory. So, when the whole thing is executed output of pwd will replace its position and serve as the argument to `chmod` , and the result is that all your present working directory get the permission `777` which I guess should never be used in production environment ;) .