# Assign regular expression as character for a variable

Tags: shell, quoting, wildcards

I am wondering is there is a way to assign a regular expression as a character in a string to a variable and not have the regular expression change my variable.

For example:
in my directory I am working on I have: `A.cc`, `A.hh`, and `foo.sh`.

In `foo.sh`:

```
var=$(A*)

echo $var
```

I am trying to assign to `var` specifically `A*` and not `A.cc`, `A.hh`, which is what happening with `*`.

I am using `/bin/sh`.

Comment: use `var=A*; printf "%s\n" "$var"`. see: [What is $() in a command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/147420/what-is-in-a-command), [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters) and [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo)

Answer (score 1):

use quotes to stop bash from globbing.

```
var="A*"
echo "$var"
```