# Getting directory name from file without full path

Tags: bash

I am trying to get the directory name of this file, which is not located in my current directory:

```
/home/me/PhD/file.tsv
```

when I run:

```
dirname /home/me/PhD/file.tsv
```

I get:

```
/home/me/PhD/
```

But, I would like to obtain just: `PhD`

How can I do this?

Comment: What OS are you running?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor I am using an enterprise linux server

Comment: Okay, I've edited the question:

when I run exactly `dirname file.tsv`I get `.` and when I run `dirname /home/me/PhD/file.tsv`I get `/home/me/PhD/`

Comment: The trailing slash looks suspicious but it doesn't matter that much, I guess.

Comment: Yes but what OS? I could guess that it is a Gnu/Linux.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor Yes, Linux

Comment: Linux is a kernel, not an operating system. So that does not help. Which OS?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
basename "$(dirname /home/me/PhD/file.tsv)"
```

Notes:

- `dirname` and `basename` operate purely on strings. It doesn't matter if the path exists.
- `$()` is explained here: [What is `$()` in a command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/147420/108618)