# Why can't I kill a SIGSTOP'd process with a SIGTERM, and where is the pending signal stored?

Tags: process, kill, signals

I am using Debian stretch (systemd).
I was running the rsyslog daemon in foreground using
`/usr/sbin/rsyslogd -n`
and I did a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to stop it. 
The state of the process changed to `Tl` (stopped, threaded).
I issued multiple `kill -15 <pid>` commands to the process, and the state of the process was the same: `Tl`. Once I did an `fg`, it died. I have 3 questions.

- Why was the `SIGSTOP`-ed process not responding to `SIGTERM`? Why does the kernel keeps it in the same state?
- Why did it get killed the moment it received the `SIGCONT` signal?
- If it was because of the previous `SIGTERM` signal, where was it kept until the process resumed?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

`SIGSTOP` and `SIGKILL` are two signals that cannot be caught and handled by a process. `SIGTSTP` is like `SIGSTOP` except that it *can* be caught and handled.

The `SIGSTOP` and `SIGTSTP` signals stop a process in its tracks, ready for `SIGCONT`. When you send that process a `SIGTERM`, the process isn't running and so it cannot run the code to exit.

(There are also `SIGTTIN` and `SIGTTOU`, which are signals generated by the TTY layer when a backgrounded job tries to read or write to the terminal. They can be caught but will otherwise stop (suspend) the process, just like `SIGTSTP`. But I'm now going to ignore those two for the remainder of this answer.)

Your <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> sends the process a `SIGTSTP`, which appears not to be handled specially in any way by `rsyslogd`, so it simply suspends the process pending `SIGCONT` or `SIGKILL`.

The solution here is also to send `SIGCONT` after your `SIGTERM` so that the process can receive and handle the signal.

Example:

```
sleep 999 &

# Assume we got PID 456 for this process
kill -TSTP 456    # Suspend the process (nicely)
kill -TERM 456    # Terminate the process (nicely). Nothing happens
kill -CONT 456    # Continue the process so it can exit cleanly
```

The documentation for the [GNU C Library](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Job-Control-Signals.html) explains this quite well, I think (my highlighting):

> **While a process is stopped, no more signals can be delivered to it until it is continued**, except `SIGKILL` signals and (obviously) `SIGCONT` signals. The signals are marked as pending, but not delivered until the process is continued. **The `SIGKILL` signal always causes termination of the process and can’t be blocked, handled or ignored.** You can ignore `SIGCONT`, but it always causes the process to be continued anyway if it is stopped. Sending a `SIGCONT` signal to a process causes any pending stop signals for that process to be discarded. Likewise, any pending `SIGCONT` signals for a process are discarded when it receives a stop signal

Comment: Thanks @roaima. Could you please help me understand why, after I issued a kill -15 and then a SIGCONT,  it gets killed? Was it because of the kill -15 that I issued before?

Comment: @nohup. answer extended, but essentially, "yes; it handled the `kill -15` you'd already sent".

Comment: So is the `SIGTERM` stored as a pending signal when send to a `SIGSTOP`'d process, and issued once the process is `SIGCONT`'d ?

Comment: @nohup yes, as per the documentation: « _While a process is stopped, no more signals can be delivered to it until it is continued ... The signals are marked as pending, but not delivered until the process is continued._ »

Comment: See also SIGTTIN and SIGTTOU that also stop processes

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas good point. I've added mention of these but otherwise ignored them. Please feel free to edit as you see fit.

Comment: Learning these discrepancies reminds my of my Op Sys class (*shudders*). Good answer and will probably help a lot of future junior and senior level CS students haha

Comment: Truth is you rarely have to deal with this stuff as a user. As a user, send SIGSTOP to pause SIGCONT to continue and SIGKILL to end a process. There are a bunch of reasons why that oversimplification sucks, but it doesn't matter.  As a developer you may or may not have to care depending on framework.  So while interesting, *all* of the signals are just an academic excersize. You want to focus on SIGSTOP, SIGCONT,  and SIGKILL for day to day stuff. SIGTERM is a nice one to learn too, but not really needed (as a user)

Comment: @coteyr. I disagree: `SIGKILL` prevents an app from cleaning up, so using `SIGTERM` is preferable in many (most) cases.

Comment: @roaima - good point. But as a user, usually you don't care. It's more "it no worky how do I kill it?" At the point that an average user would throw a SIGTERM or SIGKILL the point is not usually valid. But I will say, that leaning SIGTERM is not a bad thing and as an admin definitely a tool you need in your tool box.

Answer (score 10):

`SIGTERM` is just like any other [signal](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) in that [it can be caught](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) by a process. Receiving the signal will just make the process jump to a special signal handler routine. For `SIGTERM` the default action will be to terminate the process, but e.g. an editor might like to catch the signal so it can save a draft copy of any open files before dying. If the process is stopped, it cannot run the signal handler, but the signal will remain pending until the process continues. Note that the *number* of signals sent will usually not be saved.

In theory, the system could know if the process has a signal handler installed for `SIGTERM`, and terminate it immediately if not. But (as per Gilles' comment) POSIX demands that the signal will pend until the process is continued via `SIGCONT`.

Comment: Apologies, my previous comment was wrong. While a process is stopped, no signals are delivered to it except SIGKILL and SIGCONT. Even if the signal has its default action which is to kill the process, this is delayed until the process is resumed by a SIGCONT. POSIX mandates this behavior.