# Why `kill %jobnumber` not working on stopped jobs?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, jobs

I'm running few tasks side by side on an ubuntu 18 LTS. So I'm switching between these jobs by running

```
# command &
# fg
# fg -
```

(Also) use of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> sometimes to send running job to background.

Say I have 3 jobs in my list

```
# jobs
[1]+  Stopped                 nano /etc/nginx/site-available/blog.conf
[2]   Stopped                 top
[3]-  Stopped                 nano script.sh
```

I can successfully switch between these, but when I run `kill` command on these, jobs still showing in the list, none gets killed, I wonder why?

```
# kill %1
```

I list again, and jobs are still there.

```
# jobs
[1]+  Stopped                 nano /etc/nginx/site-available/blog.conf
[2]   Stopped                 top
[3]-  Stopped                 nano script.sh
```

Comment: @Stephen Kitt @AdminBee the question is particularly about this: `kill %1` not working. I can kill process with process id, but why not like this?

Comment: I believe it is related, but not dupe.

Comment: Re-opened. Does this apply to all your stopped jobs?

Comment: What shell are you running and does it make a difference if you use another shell?

Comment: The kill is remembered, but they might have a signal handler installed. They need to be allowed to run, even if the signal immediately terminates them. fg them and they will exit.

Comment: @Stephen Kitt Ok while this question was locked here, I got it posted on askubuntu forum, and got answer too. You can link these if you want as duplicates now. Here's link to that question. 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1216309/why-does-kill-jobnumber-not-work-on-stopped-jobs/1216319#1216319

Comment: OK, so based on the answer to your AU question, the difference isn’t `kill %1` v. `kill PID`, and [my original duplicate](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/298644/86440) was correct.