# How do I start 3 processes on the same terminal, and then exit all 3 easily?

Tags: bash, process-management

I can easily start 3 processes on 3 different terminals, and kill each one by pressing <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>. Now, is there any way to start all 3 processes at once, and then finish them equally easily? Ideas:

1. If I could start 3 processes in such a way that they would run on the same terminal, and <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> would kill all 3, that would work.
2. If I could create two scripts, `init.sh` and `kill.sh` that would start/kill the 3 processes, that would work too.

Both of those work because they are easy. Having to spawn a process on the background, then finding its pid, then copying it, then killing it with yet another command isn't easy.

Comment: Learn bash job control. http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x9644.html

Comment: As you're talking about the number of terminals, you can also make use of some terminal multiplexer, namely `tmux(1)` or `screen(1)` :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using bash's job control:

```
$ sleep 10m & sleep 11m & sleep 12m &
[1] 1821
[2] 1822
[3] 1823
$ jobs
[1]   Running                 sleep 10m &
[2]-  Running                 sleep 11m &
[3]+  Running                 sleep 12m &
$ kill %1 %2 %3
$ jobs
[1]   Terminated: 15          sleep 10m
[2]-  Terminated: 15          sleep 11m
[3]+  Terminated: 15          sleep 12m
```

In bash, running `command &` sends it to the background. This way, you can start multiple commands in the same shell, running in the background. The `kill` builtin can be used to kill these background jobs. The first (oldest) active job is `%1`, the next is `%2` and so on. Also see: [Kill all background jobs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/43527/70524)