# How can we kill all the background jobs (running or not) in the current shell?

Tags: bash, background-process, jobs

From https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/43709/674

> To just `kill` all background jobs managed by `bash`, do
>
> ```
> kill $(jobs -p)
> ```

Does `kill $(jobs -p)` kill only those "running" background jobs in the current shell, but not those background jobs in the shell which are in "stopped" or some other states?

How can we kill all the background jobs in the current shell, regardless of whether they are in running, stopped or some other states?

For example, I created two stopped jobs, by running `less` and then `ctrl+z`:

```
$ ps | less

[1]+  Stopped                 ps | less
$ less recover_jobs.sh

[2]+  Stopped                 less recover_jobs.sh

$ jobs -l
[1]-  2753 Done                    ps
      2754 Stopped                 | less
[2]+  2842 Stopped                 less recover_jobs.sh
$ jobs -p
2753
2842

$ kill $(jobs -p)
bash: kill: (2753) - No such process
$ kill 2754
$ kill 2842
$ jobs -l
[1]-  2753 Done                    ps
      2754 Stopped                 | less
[2]+  2842 Stopped                 less recover_jobs.sh

$ fg 1
ps | less
Terminated
$ fg 2
less recover_jobs.sh
Terminated
```

I was wondering why:

- `kill $(jobs -p)` doesn't kill any `stopped` job,
- `jobs -p` doesn't show the pid 2754 of the stopped job `| less`, but the pid 2753 of the done job `ps`,
- `kill 2754` and `kill 2842` don't kill the stopped jobs for `| less` and for `less recover_jobs.sh`, and
- when I `fg` the stopped jobs, they are immediately shown `Terminated` but not before I `fg` them?

Thanks.

Comment: `jobs -p | xargs -I{} kill -9 -{}` might do a better job at killing all a shell's background processes.

Answer (score 4):

`kill $( jobs -p )` would send the `TERM` signal to all *jobs*, regardless of whether they are running or not. A job may include several processes, but only the first process in each job would be signalled (see further below).

Your first and third and last question has the same answer.  A stopped job does not *receive* any signals. A signal handler (even the default one) runs in the process, and the process is *stopped*.  The signals are *delivered* when the job resumes.

As for the second question, I believe that `jobs -p` only gives you the process ID of the *first* process in the pipeline, whereas `jobs -l` lists all processes belonging to all jobs. Killing the first process of a pipeline would close the file descriptor that the next process is reading from, prompting an end-of-file on its next read attempt.